# Returned Ajax result, loop the returned object in a datalist

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm currently using an input in my blade and an ajax call in order to pass the value of an input field to a function which queries an endpoint. This calls on each keystroke.

When I debug in chrome and check the network tab, I can see that it returns the object from the ajax call successfully. The problem is, I'm looping on the object in the datalist attached to the input field and it's not filling with results.

This is supposed to be an autocomplete type of functionality where the ajax call queries and returns results which will show and filter in the datalist. The way I'm looping the object in my blade works when I copy the object into the file in a hard coded value. I'm wondering if I need something else in my Ajax in order to pass it back properly.

Again, my Ajax call is successful and returns the object, but what do I need to do in order to make my `return response()->json($searchResults);` return to the datalist for my input?

controller.php

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
       $search_result = $request->search_result;

       $service = new service();

        $searchResults = $service->getSearch($search_result);

        return response()->json($searchResults);
    }
}
```

view.blade.php

```
 <input id ="productInput"  class="uk-search-field" type="search" placeholder="search products..." list="returnedProducts">
    <datalist id="returnedProducts">
        @if ($searchResults->hits)
            @foreach($searchResults->hits as $arr)
                @foreach($arr as $obj)
                <option value="{{$obj->_source->category}}">{{$obj->_source->category}}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </datalist>

<script type="text/javascript">

//input event handler
$('#productInput').on('input', function(){
    if($(this).val() === ''){
       return;
    }else{

       const searchResult = $(this).val(); 

       $.ajax({ url: '/account/autocomplete', 
                data: {
                    search_result:searchResult
                },
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                type: "POST", 
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
    }

});
</script>
```

Update :

```
+"took": 3
+"timed_out": false
+"_shards": {#1141 ▶}
+"hits": {#1309 ▼
  +"total": 231
  +"max_score": null
  +"hits": array:10 [▼
      0 => {#1191 ▼
      +"_index": "products"
      +"_type": "product"
      +"_id": "1634"
      +"_score": 5.7772136
      +"_source": {#1214 ▼
       +"category": "General 1234:0 - Dark Green 123:25"
```

Comment: Let's see a sample of your output and the html element where you intend to display the result.

Comment: I can put a sample up shortly, but the data list option is where I'm intending to display

Comment: Cool. Standing by.

Comment: Ok it's posted now

Comment: This looks more like an output of `dd()`. I need the output of `console.log(response)`.

Comment: I don't get anything with that, this is what I get in the network tab in Chrome's dev tools

Comment: Is there any output for `console.log(JSON.parse(response.hits.hits))`...?

Comment: I get "unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: Without the json. Parse it returned the elements of the object though, as I would expect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178967/discussion-between-chukwuemeka-inya-and-tom-n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following our chat, replace your `success` callback with this:

```
<script>
    success: function(response){
        let searchResult = response.hits.hits;
        for(let i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) {
            $("#returnedProducts").append("<option value=" + searchResult[i]._source.category + ">" + searchResult[i]._source.category + "</option>");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, mid-drive home but I'll be trying this as soon as I'm at a computer. Thanks!

Comment: OK so I finally got append to work using searchResult[i]._source.category. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh! Good. We missed that. Let me edit my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! So this doesn't seem to filter results? Meaning, if I type a letter that returns 10 results and another letter that returns only 5, the data list should only show the newest 5 that match full input

Comment: The filtering of your results is more of an elaticsearch problem. Can you confirm that as you type, ajax sends the request to PHP...right?

Comment: Yes it does for every keystroke. So it returns properly on the event but the datalist shows everything from each keystroke

Comment: I feel like I'm almost there. That seems to only show the latest in the results now as opposed to all matches returned. So console showed 5 results but only one appears in the datalist